# Are there $\in$-antichains of all cardinalities?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Say that a set $X$ is a $\in$-antichain iff 
$x\not\in y$ for any $x,y\in X$. Are there 
$\in$-antichains of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ ? More generally,
for any ordinal $\alpha$, is there a $\in$-antichain
of cardinality $\alpha$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal, and for each $\xi\in\kappa$ let $A_\xi=\kappa\setminus\{\xi\}$. Then $\{A_\xi:\xi\in\kappa\}$ is an $\in$-antichain of power $\kappa$.

Comment: Indeed, we have $A_{\zeta}\not\in A_{\xi}$ because $A_{\zeta}$ is not an ordinal and $A_{\xi}$ only contains ordinals. That's neat!

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to Brian M. Scott's answer, but perhaps a bit simpler.

Given any ordinal $\alpha > 0$ the family $\{ \{ \xi \} : \xi \in \alpha \setminus \{ 0 \} \}$ is an $\in$-antichain.  (If $\xi , \eta \in \alpha \setminus \{ 0 \}$ are such that $\{ \xi \} \in \{ \eta \}$, then $\{ \xi \} = \eta$, meaning, in particular, that $\{ \xi \}$ is also an ordinal. But the only ordinal $\xi$ such that $\{ \xi \}$ is also an ordinal is $0$, which we have explicitly omitted.)

Answer (score 3):

Without using ordinals at all *(in fact, this construction shows that for any set $X$, there is an $\epsilon$-antichain in bijection with $X$; without the axiom of choice, the other answers don't do this)*:

Suppose I have any family of distinct sets whatsoever, $\{A_i: i\in I\}$. I can turn this into an $\in$-antichain of the same size: let $$B_i=\{\{A_i\}, \{\{A_i\}\}\}.$$ Then each $B_i$ is a set with exactly two elements, each of which has exactly one element; so we never have $B_i\in B_j$.

---

Meanwhile, it's easy to show $B_i=B_j\implies i=j$: suppose $B_i=B_j$. Then we have two possibilities:

- $\{A_i\}=\{A_j\}$, or
- $\{A_i\}=\{\{A_j\}\}$ and $\{\{A_i\}\}=\{A_j\}$.

In the first case, we clearly have $i=j$. In the second case, we have $$\{A_j\}=\{\{A_i\}\}=\{\{\{A_j\}\}\},$$ which contradicts Foundation. Note however that we *do* need the axiom of Foundation to handle this case: I believe it is consistent with NF that we can have $i\not=j$ but $B_i=B_j$.

---

EDIT: So as a side question, we can ask what set-theoretic axioms we need to prove "there is an $\in$-antichain of every size." Choice and Foundation are the obviously useful ones, but what is *necessary*? It's not clear that there's a clean answer, but let me note one very weak axiom which is enough:

> If there is no "set of all sets," then there are $\in$-antichains of every size.

Proof: Fix any set $X$, and let $y\not\in X$. Then the set $Y=\{\{\{y\}, \{x\}\}: x\in X\}$ is an $\in$-antichain in bijection with $X$. We're using the fact that $y\not\in X$ to argue that $Y$ is in fact an $\in$-antichain, since $y\not\in X$ implies that every element of $Y$ is a two-element set of one-element sets.

Also, note that the only axioms we needed to get this implication (that is, the *base theory* we work over) were basically extensionality, singleton, and "Cartesian products exist."

Now, that this isn't as strong a result as it seems: there are natural(ish?) set theories which *do* allow (in fact, require) a set-of-all-sets, such as New Foundations (NF). Still, it's neat.

If this sort of question interests you, you may be interested in **Reverse Mathematics**! $<$/shamelessplug$>$

Comment: Let $B_i = \{ \{ \{A_i \}\}, i \}$. This fixes your problem without complicating the argument. Oh, we should require $I \subseteq \operatorname{Ord}$ in this case.

Comment: That doesn't work: what if we have $i=\{\{A_j\}\}$ and $j=\{\{A_i\}\}$? Then $B_i=B_j=\{i, j\}$.

Comment: Yes, in my mind $I$ only consisted of ordinals.

Comment: Note that even if we assume $I\subset ON$, that construction doesn't show that there are $\in$-antichains of all sizes - unless we assume the axiom of choice! Interestingly, that construction at the same time doesn't use the axiom of Foundation - it's enough to have the choice principle, "Every set is in bijection with a Von Neumann ordinal." I wonder if we can do away with both Foundation and Choice at once . . .

Comment: We might have $\{y,x\} \in y$, right? Btw. I find these weak theory pretty confusing, but I'm glad you brought up this question. I wonder if this should become a separate question?

Comment: I needed more curly braces, as it turns out :P But the objection you raise wouldn't be a problem: sure, we might have $\{y, x_0\}\in y\in \{y, x_1\}$, but "$\in$" isn't transitive, so this is still an antichain.

Comment: I meant to write '$=$' instead of '$\in$' - it's been a long day... :D

Comment: Hm, your edited construction now seems to make use of some form of replacement...

Comment: I know this is an oldie, but I ran across it and really wanted to figure out if it was true that you could have $i\neq j$ and $B_i=B_j$ in NF... If I'm not mistaken, you can do the following: take a model with two Quine atoms as $A_i,A_j$, and then form the Rieger-Bernays permutation model that swaps the Quine atoms and leaves everything else fixed. Then in the new model, $A_i\neq A_j$, $A_i=\{A_j\}$ and $A_j=\{A_i\}$, and $B_i=B_j=\{A_i,A_j\}$. (There's some stratification stuff to work around, but if $I$ is a two element set it works all the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another proof:

Let $( V_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord} )$ be the [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe#Definition) and for all $x$ let $\operatorname{rk}(x)$ denote the $\in$-rank of $x$, i.e. least $\alpha$ such that $x \in V_{\alpha +1}$. Note that $\operatorname{card}(V_{\alpha+1} \setminus V_\alpha) \ge \alpha$ and that $x \in y$ implies $\operatorname{rk}(x) < \operatorname{rk}(y)$. Thus any subset $X \subseteq V_{\alpha+1} \setminus V_\alpha$ of size $\alpha$ will do.

Comment: Note that this argument also gives $\in$-antichains of any size, even without choice: for $X$ an arbitrary set, let $\kappa$ be large enough that $X\in V_\kappa$, and now consider the set $\{\{\kappa, x\}: x\in X\}$. We've fit $X$ into some layer of the $V$-hierarchy, so we have an $\in$-antichain.

Comment: @Noah So far, this is my favorite construction. We probably should remark that $\kappa \not \in X$ as $X \in V_\kappa$ implies $X \subset V_\kappa$ and $\kappa \in V_{\kappa+1} \setminus V_\kappa$ in case that OP doesn't already know about these facts.

Comment: @Noah And btw, we have to require $\kappa > 1$ to avoid an ugly counterexample...